# What does the or operator do in this bit of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So I was browsing the JQuery source for better programming tips, and I found a bit of code where I'm not sure what's going on.

```
type = type || callback;
```

Can anyone explain what the OR || is doing in the variable assignment?

I did a few experiments, setting and un-setting values and what-not, but I'm none the wiser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `type` is a "falsey" value, then the value of `callback` will be assigned to the `type` variable, otherwise `type` will be assigned.

The "falsey" values are:

- `false`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `0`
- `""` (empty string)
- `NaN`

So basically it says *"replace `type` with `callback` if `type` is any one of the falsey values"*.

Consider this:

```
var type = undefined;

type = type || "default value";
```

The `type` variable will ultimately get `"default value"` assigned.

If it was like this:

```
var type = "some value";

type = type || "default value";
```

Then it would keep its `"some value"`.

Answer (score 2):

It sets the variable "type" to either its current value, or the value of "callback" if the current value is not "truthy". If "type" is `undefined`, or `null`, or 0, or the empty string, or boolean `false`, then it'll be set to the value of "callback".

*edit* oops or `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

So I see multiple variables can be 'chained' together and the first "non-falsey" value is assigned.

```
var val, a, b, c;
a = undefined;
b = null;
c = "C";
val = a || b || c;
alert(val);
```

That's pretty damn handy.

Comment: `a || ( b || c)` feels wrong to me. You shouldn't need to check whether your default value is falsy or not.