# what does this do in js "xin || {}"?

Tags: javascript, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does var x = x || {} ;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563153/what-does-var-x-x)

I have this lines in js, it is simple i am sure but i am not sure what the last part does - `(xin || {})`

```
var xin = (function (name) {return name;}(xin || {}));
```

as I understand it, xin is a object constructor so now I can create object of xin. Just not too sure what the `xin || {}` does. Can someone enlighten me please, thanks

Comment: This question has been asked many times already. Looking for dups now...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does var x = x || {} ;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563153/) or [What does the or operator do in this bit of JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863516/) or [What does this Javascript line do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643740/) take your pick (no, it is not easy to search for something like `javascript || {}`)

Comment: @Matt Ball: Just wondering, how do you get Google/SO to search for characters as well? If I do a search for `javascript || {}` then Google seems to ignore the four symbols.

Comment: @pimvdb you don't. I just searched for [`what does this do in JavaScript`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?&tab=relevance&q=what%20does%20this%20do%20in%20javascript) and skimmed through a few pages of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xin || {}
```

is the same as:

```
xin ? xin : {};
```

or, in longer form:

```
if(xin) {
    return xin;
}
else {
    return {};
}
```

---

**EDIT:** [See linked duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563153/what-does-var-x-x). jAndy puts it nicely:

`||` is the logical `OR`.

The expression

```
var x = x OR {};
```

should become more obvious then.

If `x` has a **falsy** value (like `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`), we assign `x` an empty object `{}`, otherwise just keep the current value. The long version of this would look like

```
var x = x ? x : {};
```

Comment: i think you meant `(typeof(xin) != "undefined") ? xin : new Object();`

Comment: @32bitkid — Which would still be wrong, since `||` doesn't care about type, just truth.

Comment: @Quentin very true, i'm not saying its the right answer, but at least it would be somewhat valid valid syntax.

Answer (score 4):

that attributes to the `name` argument the value of the variable `xin` if it is not false (or undefined or null) or a new object (`{}`);

example :

```
var name = xin || {};
```

this is translated into :

```
if(xin)
    var name = xin;
else
    name = {};
```

In javascript you can use the conditional operators (`||` and `&&`) to create expressions. Here's an example :

```
typeof f === 'function' && ((arguments.length ==  0 && f()) || f.apply({},arguments)) || g();
```

this expression can be translated into the following :

```
if(typeof f === 'function')
    {
        if(arguments.length == 0)
            f();
        else
            f.apply({},arguments);
    }
else
    g();
```

Anyway, this is just for demo purposes only, you shouldn't use large nested expressions built with conditional operators because it's highly unreadable (therefore very hard to maintain).

This kind of expression is often used on initializations , when you do not want to overwrite a certain value if it already exists. An good example would be the usage of a namespace within multiple js files. Using this technique (`var namespace = namespace || {};`) you can share the same namespace in all the files without overwriting it.

Comment: right.. anything that is `falsely`

Comment: @Martin — Yes, it is. What did you think putting `(expression)` after the function would do?

Comment: @Martin — Because the choice between being a function declaration (which is subject to hoisting) and a function expression (which is evaluated at runtime) is determined by the context in which the `function` keyword appears, and you can't self-execute a function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

It evaluates to xin if xin is truthy, otherwise a new object is used.

Answer (score 1):

```
a || b
```

The OR operator `||` is short circuited. That means if `a` is true then the `a || b` is true and thus it does not evaluate `b`. It returns `a` which is true. If `a` is not true then it returns `b`, i.e. in this case if `b` is false then the expression is false and is true if `b` is true. So `xin || {}` returns `xin` if `xin` is true, otherwise it returns an empty object `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var xin = (function (name) {return name;}(xin || {}));
```

is identical to this:

```
var xin = xin || {};
```

Which can be re-expressed as:

```
var xin = xin ? xin : {};
```

Simplifying further, we get:

```
if(!xin) xin = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there´s none xin object it craetes a new, so, it passes the new (or the existing) xin to the function.

This is a commom construction for artificial namespaces.